# Is it possible to change the color of 'NaN' in the VSC Data Viewer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Dataframes with a lot of columns and NaN can be hard to read. Is it possible to e.g. darken the NaN color to make the non-NaN cells pop out more?

[image]